# Next.js meta tags not being indexed by crawlers

Tags: reactjs, next.js

This question may be a duplicate but I've tried all the other solutions available here, so my issue is that my meta tags aren't getting indexed by google... I checked my URL's with this tool: https://metatags.io/, and it says it has no title or description, but my title tag still shows in the text in my chrome tab, This issue is in both client and server side rendered pages, here is my code

```
import React from "react";
import Head from "next/head";

import Footer from "../../components/Footer";
import Header from "../../components/Header";

const AboutUs = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>
          Sample Title
        </title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="keyword 1, keyword 2" />
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Test Description"
        />
      </Head>
      <Header />
      ...
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default AboutUs;
```

Here's my code for `_app.js`

```
import Head from "next/head";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { PersistedStore, Store } from "../redux/store";

import "../styles/styles.css";
import "../styles/globals.css";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"
        />

        <link
          rel="apple-touch-icon"
          sizes="180x180"
          href="./assets/images//apple-touch-icon.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="icon"
          type="image/png"
          sizes="32x32"
          href="/assets/images/favicon-32x32.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="icon"
          type="image/png"
          sizes="16x16"
          href="/assets/images/favicon-16x16.png"
        />
        <link rel="manifest" href="./assets/images/site.webmanifest" />

        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;500;600;700&amp;display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />

        <link
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick-theme.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />

        <script
          src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"
          type="text/javascript"
        ></script>
        <script
          src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"
          type="text/javascript"
        ></script>
      </Head>

      <Provider store={Store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={PersistedStore}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Do you have an `_app` page? If so, can you show us the code for that page too?

Comment: I do, I edited the question with the file...

Comment: The `PersistGate` most likely makes the code you have in your pages only render on the client-side. This means the metatags you set in the pages will not be part of the initial server response.

Comment: Yes, removing it seems to solve the issue, thanks a lot

Comment: This solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72966026/issue-with-meta-tags-when-using-redux-persist-in-next-js