# Issue with meta tags when using redux-persist in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I'm building an e-commerce app with Next.js and redux. I have noticed that when I add redux-persist to the app all meta tags stop working. I have added my code snippets below

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import shopReducer from './reducers/shop/shopSlice'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import { persistStore,persistReducer, FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER } from 'redux-persist'

const initState = {}

const persistConfig = {
   key: 'root',
   version: 1,
   storage,
   whitelist: ['shop'],
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   shop: shopReducer,
})

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

const reduxStore = () => {
   const store = configureStore ({
       initState,
       reducer: persistedReducer,
       middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
       getDefaultMiddleware({
          serializableCheck: {
             ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
          },
       }),
   })

   const persistor = persistStore(store)
   return { persistor, store }
}

export default reduxStore
```

Then in `_app.js`

```
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import reduxStore from '../context/store'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

const { persistor, store } = reduxStore()

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }){
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
                <Layout>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </Layout>
            </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

The `meta tags` component is like this excluding the other tags.

```
import Head from 'next/head'

function Meta({ title, keywords, description, image, appName, url }){
    return (
        <Head>
            <meta name="theme-color" content="#0066b2" />
            <meta name="description" content={description} />
            <meta name="keywords" content={keywords} />
            <meta name="author" content="author" />
            <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
            <meta name="twitter:title" content={title} />
            <meta name="twitter:description" content={description} />
            <meta property="twitter:image" content={image} />
            <meta property="twitter:image:alt" content={appName} />
            <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff" />
            <title>{title}</title>
        </Head>
    )
}

Meta.defaultProps = {
    appName: 'Store',
    url: 'https://example.com',
    title: 'Store Example',
    keywords: 'ecommerce',
    description: 'Store',
    image: '/storefront.png',
}

export default Meta
```

How can I fix the issue because I want to use both - redux-persist to save a guest shopping cart and meta tags for SEO?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found a solution on this [Github link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8240). Apparently there's an issue with `redux-persist` which disables SSR and that's basically why meta tags don't work when using redux-persist.

The solution is to change the code below

```
<PersistGate persistor={persistor} loading={null}>
    <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
</PersistGate>
```

to this

```
<PersistGate persistor={persistor} loading={null}>
    {() => (
        <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
    )}
</PersistGate>
```

Comment: holy..., thank you so much. I was strugling hours to solve this

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still facing this same error, here's another solution to this.

This issue with the initial solution is UI Rehydration problem would occur frequently on SSG pages, see why (https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error)

```
const PersistGateComponent = dynamic(
  () =>
    import('redux-persist/integration/react').then((mod) => mod.PersistGate),
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);

const SSROutset = ({ children, persistor }) => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    return (
      <PersistGateComponent
        persistor={persistor}
      >
        {children}
      </PersistGateComponent>
    );
  }

  // You can create a visually hidden component to avoid layout flashes and also maintain SEO content
  // see Chakra for an example of one https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/visually-hidden
  return <VisuallyHidden>{children}</VisuallyHidden>;
};
```

Usage

```
   <Provider store={store}>
    <SSROutset persistor={store.__persistor}>
      <Component .... />
    </SSROutset>
   </Provider>
```

Please let me know if this resolves your issue. With this solution, rehydration challenges are effectively addressed, ensuring that your states are consistently bootstrapped and persisted in the correct manner.

NB: this is also with the `next-redux-wrapper` implementation.