# Using redux-persist with redux toolkit somehow removes html elements

Tags: next.js, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

When I use redux-persist and render app using **PersistGate**, I don't know why html elements from server side does not render and once I remove **PersistGate**, it get rendered from server. I have search alot of articles but couldn't find solution.
I'm using redux-persist with redux toolkit.

Here is my `store.js` code

```
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from "redux-persist";

import authUserReducer from "./authUser";
import { combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import createWebStorage from "redux-persist/lib/storage/createWebStorage";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  authUser: authUserReducer,
});

const createNoopStorage = () => {
  return {
    getItem(_key) {
      return Promise.resolve(null);
    },
    setItem(_key, value) {
      return Promise.resolve(value);
    },
    removeItem(_key) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    },
  };
};

const storage =
  typeof window !== "undefined"
    ? createWebStorage("local")
    : createNoopStorage();

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
  middleware: [thunk],
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Issue with meta tags when using redux-persist in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72966026/issue-with-meta-tags-when-using-redux-persist-in-next-js).